# Return == in Java

Tags: java

I've been trying to find the meaning of returning == from a method. But I'm not sure what its called so I can't find any explanations online. If someone could point me to the correct resources or the name so I can search it that would be great. This is an example of what I don't understand.

```
public boolean isFull() 
{
  return length == entry.length;
}
```

Comment: Think of it like `if (length == entry.length)`.  If `length` is equal to `entry.length` it will evaluate to `true`, otherwise it will be `false`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java && || in RETURN statements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556993/java-in-return-statements)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `length` is equal to `entry.length`, this returns `true`.  Otherwise, it returns `false`.

This is just evaluating the expression `length == entry.length` and returning the result of that expression.

Answer (score 14):

`length == entry.length` is just a boolean expression. This is the same as:

```
public boolean isFull() {
    boolean answer = (length == entry.length);
    return answer;
}
```

The form you quoted is more succinct, and generally preferred.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't returning `==`, it's returning the result of `length == entry.length`. `==` is an operator which returns true when its left and right side are equal and false otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

It has a boolean return type

```
boolean
```

So it will return either true or false. The condition of true/false is based on these 2 operands

```
length
```

and

```
entry.length
```

The operator

```
==
```

Check whether both operands is equal to each other or not.

Answer (score 2):

You are not really 'returning ==' but merely the result of some comparison.  As you see the return type is a boolean - so either true or false.  In your sample, comparing a field named length against the length of a property named entry.

Answer (score 1):

`length == entry.length` is an [equality expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21): "The type of an equality expression is always boolean."

The return statement is simply returning the value of an expression whose type matches the declared type of the method, `boolean`.