# Java && || in RETURN statements?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion, syntax, return

I'm looking at some Java algorithm examples and I come across this snippet code within a recursive method:

```
boolean subTree(TreeNode t1, TreeNode t2) {
    if (t1 == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (t1.value == t2.value) {
        if (treeMatch(t1, t2))
            return true;;
    }
    return (subTree(t1.left, t2) || subTree(t1.right, t2));
}
```

Not knowing (and never seeing) || being used within a return statement before, let alone a recursive one, really made me confused. I copied the code into Eclipse to see if it was valid and it was. I then replaced the || with && and Eclipse didn't seem bothered by it. Logically, I understand that this recursive code is supposed to continue down the left and right subtrees of TreeNode t1, but I'm looking for a more theoretical explanation behind how this Java syntax works.

Can someone explain the meaning behind || and && within Java's return statement? What does it mean in terms of recursion? Is it only meaningful when used in conjunction with recursion?

Comment: How do you usually use a `return` statement? What is the expression you give it? You can do `return a + b`, so why not `return c || d`? `||` and `&&` are just operators.

Comment: That it's recursive or an expression isn't relevant, nor is that it's recursive *and* an expression.

Comment: THe point is to return a boolean. The expression **(function(a) && function(b) ) ** is indeed a Boolean, as long as function(int) returns a boolean.

Comment: Like the others have basically said, the return statement is nothing more than an expression. The only thing "Special" is that it evaluates the expression using recursion. Also, consider replacing that line with `boolean r = (subTree(t1.left, t2) || subTree(t1.right, t2));` and then `return r;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As defined in the method signature, you will have to return a `boolean`. Therefore, after the `return` keyword, you will have to provide a `boolean` **or an expression** which is evaluated to `boolean`.

In your case  you have the expession `(subTree(t1.left, t2) || subTree(t1.right, t2));` in which the two operands will be evaluated to `boolean` and you will apply an logical `OR` on them only if the first evaluates to `false`. If the first operand evaluates to `true` the second will not be evaluated and `true` will be retured.

Answer (score 9):

They work the same way, whether there is a recursive statement in there or not. In your expression:

```
(subTree(t1.left, t2) || subTree(t1.right, t2))
```

if the first call to `subTree(t1.left, t2)` evaluates to `true`, the second expression won't be called or attempted to be evaluated. This is just the standard short-circuit behaviour of the `||` and `&&` operators and is how the operators work with any arguments given to them.

Comment: +1 The short-circuit behavior info is pretty relevant since we're talking about a recursive call.

Answer (score 1):

This is the logical or operator that will return you the boolean value

```
 return (subTree(t1.left, t2) || subTree(t1.right, t2))// return boolean value
```

and && also written you the boolean value like

```
return (subTree(t1.left, t2) && subTree(t1.right, t2))// return boolean value
```

The both operator work same as Mathematical Logic

Answer (score 0):

```
return (subTree(t1.left, t2) || subTree(t1.right, t2));
```

Evaluates the first clause `subTree(t1.left, t2)` then the second.

So the node all the way down to the leaf node will evaluate then start working back up the tree working the right node (and all it's left nodes first).

Answer (score 0):

Java's `return` gives back a single value defined by the method's body. If you think of it as a generic function (it isn't but it helps to understand), it becomes like `return(boolean result)` in your example. Now like with any other method as well, you can do inline calculations that result in an intermediate value, which is then forwarded (called *anonymously*) to the actual function like `Math.round(a + 0.5)`.

Combine that and

```
final boolean result = subTree(t1.left, t2) || subTree(t1.right, t2);
return result;
```

becomes

```
return (subTree(t1.left, t2) || subTree(t1.right, t2));
```

Answer (score 0):

Ther are just boolean and/or with short circuit.

Short circuit means it evaluates the first operand and then evaluetes the second one only if needed to decide the result. You know, true || x = true; false && x = false no matter what is the value of x so it is not even evaluated in those cases.

If the evaluation has side effects and you want them to happen always then you should use & or | that doesn't use short circuit so both operands are evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I will explain it based on the [[Java Language Specification]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.17) :

A return statement is defined as :

```
ReturnStatement:
      return Expressionopt ;
```

> A return statement with an Expression attempts to transfer control to the invoker 
>       of the method that contains it; the value of the **Expression** becomes the value 
>       of the method invocation
>
> ... **execution of such a return statement first evaluates the Expression**.

What's an expression:

> An expression is a construct made up of **variables**, **operators**, and method invocations, 
>       which are constructed according to the syntax of the language, that evaluates to a single value

```
return (subTree(t1.left, t2) || subTree(t1.right, t2));
```

Let's de-construct it:

```
return Expression; //Statement

Expression : (subTree(t1.left, t2) || subTree(t1.right, t2))
```

As already said - an expression is made up of **method invocations** , operators, etc - ***subTree***

(Result of Method Invocation subtree) Logical Operator (Result of Method Invocation subtree)

The resulting would be the value of the evaluation of the Expression.